# android:preferenceStyle do not work on the device API level 10

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles

I am using PreferenceFragment from [here](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment). and set the styles as follows, it works on ICS devices. But On Android 2.3.7(level 10), the "android:preferenceStyle" is not applied.

Actually there is only one item which is "android:layout", so if I manually set "android:layout" in every Preference, it works well. Although there is workaround now, I want it to be styled properly by preferenceStyle attribute.

Any help would be appreciated.

styles.xml

```
<style name="Preference">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/preference</item>
</style>
```

themes.xml

```
    <item name="android:preferenceStyle">@style/Preference</item>
```

xml resource

```
<PreferenceCategory android:key="pref_category_legal" android:title="@string/legal">
    <Preference android:key="pref_key_terms" android:title="@string/terms_of_service" />
    <Preference android:key="pref_key_privacy" android:title="@string/privacy_policy" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I added the codes that represent this issue.

https://github.com/sh1nj1/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

if you build the app, there are two preferences which expects to be as same look.